# I need a video player that allows renaming the video file within the application

Tags: windows, video-player, rename

I often work with videos and need to rename the videos while watching them one by one or delete them. Is there any player that allows renaming and deleting the video without having to search it in the directory each time and rename or delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File renaming and deleting is available through playlist context menu in https://tomeko.net/software/VideoPlayer/ - mplayer GUI.

Archive with mplayer included: https://github.com/tomek-o/VideoPlayer/releases/download/v2.4.0/VideoPlayer_2_4_0.7z.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TMSZ's answer, Pot Player is an excellent, feature-rich player with a user friendly interface which allows file renaming and deleting videos/audios from within the app.
By pressing F2, a dialogue box appears where the file name can be modified. The shortcut keys for this and other operations could be easily modified in settings. Pressing Del simply deletes the current video/audio and the player proceeds to the next file in the playlist.

[You can get Pot Player here.](https://potplayer.daum.net/)